# UIDatePicker using mode as timer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I have a UIDatePicker on my view,I have set DatePicker in time mode. bydefault it is showing hours and minutes and i need minutes and seconds in that picker.

Guide me that how can i use UIDatepicker for min and sec not for hour and min.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no datePickerMode for minutes and seconds. You'd have to make your own using UIPickerView.

If you look at the Apple sample project UICatalog (search for it in the apple documentation) it has examples of custom pickers so you can see how to make you own.

Comment: +1 for the [UICatalog sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) with all sorts of controls such as pickers in many different styles.